# How to write a custom dependecy property and data bind to custom type?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I have a project in winrt environment where I am trying to extend the functionality of the standard GridView control by extending it. The goal is to change the SelectedItems behaviour of the GridView.

```
public class myGridView : GridView
{

    /// <summary>
    ///  My replacement of SelectedItems
    /// </summary>
    public IObservableVector<object> appItems
    {
        get { return GetValue(AppSelectedItemsProperty) as IObservableVector<object>; }
        set { SetValue(AppSelectedItemsProperty, value);
        appItems.VectorChanged += AppSelectedItemsChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the AppSelectedItems dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppSelectedItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "appItems",
            typeof(IObservableVector<object>),
            typeof(AppGridView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, AppItemsPropertyCallback));

    ….
    ….
    ...
   }
```

In my XAML file I have the following..

```
<xx
   …….
   <appControls:AppGridView  appItems="{Binding ContactsListSelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay } }">
       .…
        …
   </appControls:AppGridView >
   …..
   …….

 /xx>
```

The final piece of code is my MVVM class that is bound to the Datacontext.

```
 public  class myModel: baseModel
 {
   ……
   ……..
   /// <summary>
    /// Not Working
    /// </summary>
    private  IObservableVector<Contact> _ContactsListSelectedItems;
    public IObservableVector<Contact> ContactsListSelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (IObservableVector<Contact>)_ContactsListSelectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty<IObservableVector<Contact>>(ref _ContactsListSelectedItems, value);              
        }
    }

 ….
 ….
}
```

I found a implementation of  IObservableVector here : https://gist.github.com/runceel/2437074

The data binding to  ContactsListSelectedItems are not working  giving the following Error:

```
Error: Cannot get 'ContactsListSelectedItems' value (type 'Object') from type 'Consius.ActiveWork.Pages.ContactPage.ContactPageViewModel, Consius.ActiveWork, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='ContactsListSelectedItems' DataItem='Consius.ActiveWork.Pages.ContactPage.ContactPageViewModel, Consius.ActiveWork, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Consius.ActiveWork.Controls.AppGridView' (Name='ContactsList'); target property is 'appItems' (type 'IObservableVector`1<Object>').
```

If I change the type of  ContactsListSelectedItems  to:

```
IObservableVector<object>
```

It all works well.

This is not a acceptable solution for me, writing my MVVM class with using the class object.

Is there anyone out there that can give me a hint whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with ObservableCollection instead of IObservableVector and that custom implementation you found?

Comment: No. I've read that IObservableCollection  will be replaced by IObservableVector,,, so I never gave it a try.

You think there can be something wrong with the implementation of ObservableVector??

Comment: Now I have written a version using ObservableCollection instead of Observable vector. 
Still I have a error:  "Converter failed to convert value of type ObservableCollection<contact> to ObservableCollection<object>"

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this same problem at the moment. There seem to be two problems.
One, if you move your type (contact) to a WinRT Component project, it gets rid of the exception that the type cannot be instantiated because it is not a legal WinRT type, but then there is a second problem that when the type is not object, the enumerator is used instead of a virtualization and the indexer. So far I cannot see a way around the problem other than using object...